# python code with large pandas DataFrame is to slow

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, profiling

I have the following code and the algorithm is pretty slow. 
I tried to use preallocation with `numpy` (1.14.3) and converting string columns in `pandas` (0.23.0) into `category` to speed up the code, but it is still very slow.

my `df` is a large `pd.DataFrame`. `len(df)` returns `1342058` and has 25 columns.

`df` contains timestamps with certain events and locations. The frequency of the data is variable, going from second data to hourly data. I basically want to resample the data for each client_id and a given date arrow (`rng`) (every 5 minutes between `start` and `end`).

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['client_id']=['40:a3:cc:XX:XX:XX','28:c6:3f:XX:XX:XX','40:a3:cc:XX:XX:XX','40:a3:cc:XX:XX:XX','28:c6:3f:XX:XX:XX','40:a3:cc:XX:XX:XX','40:a3:cc:XX:XX:XX','28:c6:3f:XX:XX:XX','28:c6:3f:XX:XX:XX','40:a3:cc:XX:XX:XX']

df['seen_time'] = ['2018-09-01 00:00:03+00:00', '2018-09-01 00:00:04+00:00','2018-09-01 00:00:05+00:00','2018-09-01 00:00:06+00:00','2018-09-01 00:00:08+00:00','2018-09-01 00:00:09+00:00','2018-09-01 00:00:09+00:00','2018-09-01 00:00:14+00:00','2018-09-01 00:00:19+00:00','2018-09-01 00:00:25+00:00']

df['location_x'] = [7.488775,20.163136,19.485196,12.841458,15.508627,5.708157,13.451071,19.1871,65,9.015443,28.266964]
```

Here is my code:

```
start = "2018-09-01 00:00"
end = "2018-09-28 00:00"
rng = pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='5T') # date range in x min.

df['client_id'] = df['client_id'].astype('category')
# --> this line already improved the speed of the algorithm by 20x

def processDataSingle(client_id):
    df_ = pd.DataFrame() # temporariy dataframe.
    data_ = np.zeros((len(rng),)).tolist() # initialize.
    dataSize = len(rng)
    for idx,d in enumerate(rng):
        t0 = d.tz_localize('UTC')
        t1 = (d + pd.to_timedelta(filter_min,unit='m')).tz_localize('UTC')
        # t0 and t1 are start and end time, with 5 min difference for the query.
        df_client = df[df['client_id']==client_id]
        # selects the data of the required client_id only.

        df_client_range = df_client[(df_client['seen_time']>=t0)&(df_client['seen_time']<t1)]
        # selects only the data for this client and between t0 and t1

        content = {
            'x_mean':df_client_range['location_x'].mean(),
            'x_median':df_client_range['location_x'].median(),
            'x_min': df_client_range['location_x'].min(),
            'x_max':df_client_range['location_x'].max()
        }
        data_[idx] = content
    # end of looping over date range.
    df_[client_id] = data_
    return df_

def processDataArrayWrapper(client_ids):
    results = np.zeros((len(client_ids),)).tolist() # preallocate!!!  a=np.zeros((2,))
    for iclient,client_id in enumerate(client_ids):
        results[iclient] = processDataSingle(client_id)
    # end looping over client_ids
    return results
#end of processDataArrayWrapper

client_ids = ['firstID','secondID','thirdID'] # in real world around 1000 IDs
%prun results = processDataArrayWrapper(client_ids)
```

the result of `prun` is the following:

```
158001796 function calls (155889787 primitive calls) in 483.930 seconds

Ordered by: internal time

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
44934  209.957    0.005  209.957    0.005 {pandas._libs.algos.take_2d_axis1_object_object}
381942   44.206    0.000   44.379    0.000 {built-in method pandas._libs.algos.ensure_int64}
22468   20.656    0.001   95.913    0.004 categorical.py:2437(_recode_for_categories)
67402   20.583    0.000   20.583    0.000 {pandas._libs.algos.take_1d_int16_int16}
3   20.274    6.758  483.715  161.238 <ipython-input-49-c130ea2c69e4>:23(processDataSingle)
44934    9.177    0.000    9.177    0.000 {pandas._libs.algos.take_2d_axis1_int64_int64}
44934    9.107    0.000    9.107    0.000 {pandas._libs.algos.take_2d_axis1_float64_float64}
36873382    7.775    0.000   15.205    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
44934    7.592    0.000    7.592    0.000 {method 'nonzero' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
11899203    4.604    0.000    5.136    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
22471    4.368    0.000    4.450    0.000 {method 'get_indexer' of 'pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine' objects}
44934    3.644    0.000    3.644    0.000 {pandas._libs.algos.take_1d_int64_int64}
22467    3.479    0.000    3.776    0.000 categorical.py:64(f)
643042    3.380    0.000    3.380    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
148422    3.016    0.000    3.016    0.000 {method 'copy' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
2557465/2534997    2.740    0.000    4.622    0.000 common.py:1835(_get_dtype_type)
337007/292073    2.727    0.000  318.981    0.001 algorithms.py:1545(take_nd)
7351676    2.672    0.000    5.713    0.000 generic.py:7(_check)
404409/359475    2.359    0.000   20.467    0.000 series.py:165(__init__)
8155845/6470735    2.152    0.000    2.873    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
471840    2.111    0.000    2.111    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.empty}
89874    2.109    0.000    4.487    0.000 internals.py:3363(_rebuild_blknos_and_blklocs)
2610562    2.028    0.000    5.330    0.000 base.py:61(is_dtype)
1046990/1002055    1.888    0.000    2.184    0.000 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.array}
44935    1.830    0.000    1.830    0.000 {method 'take' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
4713590    1.757    0.000    1.773    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
134826/89883    1.750    0.000    7.191    0.000 base.py:250(__new__)
247139    1.647    0.000    6.430    0.000 cast.py:257(maybe_promote)
1087307    1.523    0.000    5.693    0.000 common.py:1688(is_extension_array_dtype)
134802/89868    1.475    0.000   18.290    0.000 datetimes.py:329(__new__)
2233231    1.437    0.000    2.797    0.000 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:997(_handle_fromlist)
718950    1.411    0.000    2.764    0.000 generic.py:4374(__setattr__)
763890/629088    1.361    0.000    2.083    0.000 {method 'format' of 'str' objects}
224670    1.314    0.000  254.948    0.001 internals.py:1237(take_nd)
629082    1.249    0.000    2.836    0.000 internals.py:116(__init__)
314539    1.145    0.000  303.889    0.001 frame.py:2661(__getitem__)
...
67401    0.634    0.000  134.602    0.002 ops.py:1175(wrapper)
44934    0.625    0.000  277.776    0.006 internals.py:4518(take)
...
67404    0.558    0.000  101.225    0.002 categorical.py:267(__init__)
...
89868    0.527    0.000   11.864    0.000 datetimelike.py:523(take)
44934    0.522    0.000  285.513    0.006 generic.py:2780(_take)
1392955    0.517    0.000    0.599    0.000 internals.py:352(dtype)
44934/22467    0.514    0.000   12.605    0.001 {built-in method _operator.ge}
...
44937    0.425    0.000  264.034    0.006 internals.py:4423(<listcomp>)
...
763912    0.296    0.000    1.993    0.000 numeric.py:424(asarray)
44934    0.295    0.000   22.606    0.001 datetimes.py:109(wrapper)
381946    0.289    0.000    2.251    0.000 {method 'any' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
89892    0.286    0.000    0.960    0.000 common.py:298(_asarray_tuplesafe)
67404    0.281    0.000    1.299    0.000 cast.py:971(maybe_cast_to_datetime)
89868    0.280    0.000    2.962    0.000 internals.py:4108(get)
629082    0.276    0.000    0.276    0.000 internals.py:127(_check_ndim)
44934    0.276    0.000  295.073    0.007 frame.py:2704(_getitem_array)
107568    0.267    0.000    2.324    0.000 missing.py:494(na_value_for_dtype)
179742    0.264    0.000    0.827    0.000 dtypes.py:459(construct_from_string)
44937    0.260    0.000  270.290    0.006 internals.py:4388(reindex_indexer)
...
67401    0.220    0.000  128.302    0.002 ops.py:1073(dispatch_to_index_op)
...
1    0.194    0.194  483.930  483.930 <string>:1(<module>)
...
44934    0.179    0.000   20.583    0.000 base.py:89(cmp_method)
...
44934    0.110    0.000   10.841    0.000 datetimes.py:39(_maybe_cache)
...
1    0.003    0.003  483.719  483.719 <ipython-input-49-c130ea2c69e4>:61(processDataArrayWrapper)
...
1    0.000    0.000  483.930  483.930 {built-in method builtins.exec}
```

Note: I deleted a bunch of lines where `cumtime` was little. I believe the most time was consumed in `take_2d_axis1_object_object`, but I'm having difficulties in understanding the problem. Which part of the code is causing this problem?

I'm running the code on my Mac book pro with Intel Core i7 2,7 GHz with 4 cores, and the python process uses nearly 400% of CPU, which means that it somehow uses multi core in the back.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Could you provide some context or insight as to what the problem is you are trying to solve? It would help to see a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: @rahlf23 I hope my goal for the algorithm is now clear.

Comment: It would still be helpful to see an example of your dataframe. The goal here is a minimum reproducible example. At this point, it appears as though you can simply use a `groupby()` w/ `resample()` and `agg()` to accomplish your task

Comment: The DataFrame is huge. I'm going to attempt to put some data in the question, but not all the original columns.

Comment: `df[df['client_id']==client_id]` iterates through the entire dataframes each iteration of the loop. At the very least, you should `groupby('client_id')`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have not figured out yet how to use `groupby` in this example, but I'll keep exploring.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to come up with a pretty cool solution that reduces the execution from several hours to less than 15 sec.

```
def resampleData():
    results = {}
    for idx,thisIDIndex in df.groupby('client_id').groups.items():
        df_id = df.loc[thisIDIndex]
        df_id_sel = df_id[['seen_time','location_x','location_y']] # only the stuff I really need. 
        df_id_sel = df_id_sel.set_index('seen_time')
        df_id_sel_resampled_mean = df_id_sel.resample('5T').mean()
        df_id_sel_resampled_max = df_id_sel.resample('5T').max()
        df_id_sel_resampled_min = df_id_sel.resample('5T').min()
        df_id_sel_resampled_median= df_id_sel.resample('5T').median()

        df_id_sel_resampled_mean = df_id_sel_resampled_mean.rename(columns={'location_x':'x_mean', 'location_y':'y_mean'})
        df_id_sel_resampled_max = df_id_sel_resampled_max.rename(columns={'location_x':'x_max', 'location_y':'y_max'})
        df_id_sel_resampled_min = df_id_sel_resampled_min.rename(columns={'location_x':'x_min', 'location_y':'y_min'})
        df_id_sel_resampled_median = df_id_sel_resampled_median.rename(columns={'location_x':'x_med', 'location_y':'y_med'})
        DF = pd.concat([df_id_sel_resampled_min, df_id_sel_resampled_max,df_id_sel_resampled_mean, df_id_sel_resampled_median], axis=1, sort=False)
        #print('--- Index ' + idx + ' done ')
        results[idx] = DF
    # end loop over ids
    return results
#end of doStupidLoop
```

I'm now only looping over the id's, and then access the data by `groupby` as pointed out. I also use `resample` to to the job instead of iterating over the time axis. I could probably optimise the code further, but I'm happy now with the solution and it is still very explicit and easy to understand and follow.